# Calling an Enterprise bean method

Tags: ejb

Here's my Bean class source

@Stateless(mappedName="StringVal")
public class NewSessionBean implements NewSessionRemote {

```
String val = null;

public String stringChange(int parameter) {
     while(parameter < 5){
        switch (parameter){
            case 1: System.out.println(val + "One" + ",");
            case 2: System.out.println(val + "Two" + ",");
            case 3: System.out.println(val + "Three" + ",");
            case 4: System.out.println(val + "Four" + ",");
        }
    }
    return val;
}
```

}

And here's my client class for this bean (Stand Alone Client)

import endpoint.NewSessionRemote;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class TestLogicBean {

```
static String retVal = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        NewSessionRemote br = (NewSessionRemote) ctx.lookup("StringVal");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String retVal1 = br.stringChange(i);
            System.out.println("EJB message is:" + retVal1);
        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

But i'm getting this Exception "javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial"

I have tried several ways to make this,but still it gives this exception.

Comment: isn't the call to your bean's stringChange() method going to result in an infinite loop? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look what I found:

http://www.jboss.org/index.html?module=bb&op=viewtopic&t=38107

Seems like you have to had this to your jndi.properties:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
```

Looks like it's all about setting up the connection to the JNDI server.

Comment: I'm using glassfish as my server app, In there all the setting are specifically set up all the setting as mentioned here https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB but still no result

Comment: Have you done all 5 steps? It should work as advertised on the tin.